# Why JavaScript submit reload page and submit via button make client page validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have strange behavior with jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive

if I call submit mvc form like it, page is reloaded and validation working

```
  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();">
                            <div class="span2 btn">
                                <div class="span2 top10 playText">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
```

if submit form

```
 <input id="subBtn" type="image"                            
 src="/images/free.jpg"class="main_img" />
```

validation working on client side

What is the difference ? how to make it work via client side all the time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`HTMLFormElement.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) method on the DOM element (not jQuery object) submits the form without calling any attached `onsubmit` event handlers, therefore your validation is bypassed.

Conversely, Using a submit button or image does invoke any submit event handlers.

You can use the jQuery submit method instead:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

This will call any submit handlers.

Note, if your validation is your own JavaScript or jQuery validation then this is OK, if you are using HTML5 validation then you will have to trigger the click event of the submit button:

```
$('#subBtn').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger event on the submit button:

```
document.getElementById('subBtn').click();
```

Native browser validation is triggered by click on submit button, not by submitting the form - these are two different events.

Comment: why is that better than form.submit() ?

Comment: Actually the validation is triggered only on submit button click. `form.submit()` bypasses this.

Comment: You should put that in your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the form to submit values like that:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
    //Cancel the form post
    e.preventDefault();

    // ... Rest of your code validation

}
```